# Dynamicaly generated PHP multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

The simplified version of my code is below, I will eventually assign values to the number of people (this is from an sql table). I'm wondering what's wrong with my multidimensional array. It seems like everything should be associative when I'm making it, but the array that gets spit out is not what I'm looking for, because the first key isn't a value of the distance, its just an incrementing number. How do I make an array that allows me to use this as the key? (Please note that in this example I don't know how many distances there are nor the amount of people in each distance.)

```
<?php
$speed = array("ran", "walked");
$distance = array(15,10,3,5,1,2);

foreach ($distance as $key) {
  foreach ($speed as $secondarykey) {
    $array[$key][$secondarykey] = "number of people";
  }
}

print_r(array_values($array));

unset($array);

?>
```

My array that I get back looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [ran] => number of people
        [walked] => number of people
    )

)
```

It seems like there is something simple that I'm just not getting about how multidimensional arrays work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this says it all: ["array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically."](http://php.net/array_values)

Comment: @Lewis Smith may I ask why you have 2 arrays holding 2 set of information and why not combine all the information into one multidimensional array?

Comment: @unixmiah The goal is that I will make one multidimensional array using both the speed and distance arrays as variables. It appears I was already doing this, I just wasn't displaying my array correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
print_r(array_values($array));
```

To:

```
print_r( $array );
```

> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the
>   array numerically.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the output you expect because you're not printing the whole array, but just the values.  Change

```
print_r(array_values($array));
```

To:

```
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multidimentional array to form your data this way.

```
$speed = array("ran", "walked");
$distance = array(15,10,3,5,1,2);

<?php 
$distance =    array( 
                      array("ran", 15,10,3,5,1,2),
                      array("walked", 10,5,2,3,0,1)
               ); 
?>
```

Comment: The reason I'm not storing my data that way is  that I have to store a value for each intersection of the ran/walked array and the distance array. Otherwise what you are suggesting would work just fine.